# Binding IEnumerable<anonymous object> to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I need merely a readonly display of Linq data; no requirement to observe changes.  Here's the Linq:

```
string ZIPCODEFIELDNAME="zip5";
DataTable DATA = (detailedQueryResult as DataTable);
IEnumerable<object> ZIPCODE_SUMMARY;

ZIPCODE_SUMMARY = from z in DATA.AsEnumerable()
group z by z.Field<string>(ZIPCODEFIELDNAME) into g
let list = g.ToList()
select new
 {
zip = g.Key,
eecount = list.Count(),
 // possible additional aggregate columns here

};
```

I am able to bind this `IEnumerable<anonymous object>` to a Telerik RadGridView in code-behind simply by doing this:

```
myRadGridView.ItemsSource = ZIPCODE_SUMMARY.ToList();
```

that is, without having to declare a binding in XAML or having to define any columns.  How would that be accomplished using the WPF DataGrid that ships with Visual Studio?  It displays only row separators when I use the identical approach.  So it knows about the items in the list, just not how to fetch the columns.

I am trying to write some quick-and-dirty utilities to import a gazillion CSV files where no two of them have the same structure or same field names, and the fewer lines of setup code the better.

P.S. I am just getting into WPF and Linq, so please set ReplyToNovice=true :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set AutoGenerateColumns=true on the datagrid? If yes, try binding to an ICollectionView instead.

UPDATE:
Thats weird, the code below works fine for me. One thing though, you may have to set the datacontext of the datagrid to {Binding}, this will bind to the whole object.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dgZips.ItemsSource = GetFakeZips();
}

public dynamic GetFakeZips()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1500, 10).Select(i => new { Zip = i, Count = i / 4 });
}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgZips" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Comment: You surmised correctly that I'd forgotten to set AutoGenerateColumns to true, but that's not it.

Comment: Same issue -- grid row separator lines only, no column data.